# Django Reason for getting TemplateSyntaxError?

Tags: django

I have created a new app called newsletters. I can access the pages when I write their location directly from local host by writing

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/newsletters/signup/
```

but when I try to add their url in the nav bar I am getting an error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Invalid block tag on line 40: 'url'newsletters:subscribe''. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Here are the main project urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('newsletters/', include('newsletters.urls', namespace='newsletters')),
]
```

Here are newsletters app urls:

```
app_name = 'newsletters'

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', newsletter_signup, name="subscribe"),
    path('unsubscribe/', newsletter_unsubscribe, name='unsubscribe'),
]
```

here are the nav bar template:

```
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href=" {% url'newsletters:subscribe' %}">Newsletters</a>                            
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
```

How should I fix it and what am I have I done wrong to avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a space after `url` in your `url` tag:

```
{% url 'newsletters:subscribe' %}
```